# Consistency in global operations in vim

Tags: vim, sed

Consider these two vim commands

1. `:% s/one/two/g`
2. `:% g/found/d`

I am wondering why the `g` signaling global replacement and delete respectively needs to be put in the end in substitution and at the beginning in delete.

Do these follow a pattern that I am missing, or is this a vim corner case?

Comment: btw, you tagged the question with `sed` too.  has it something to do with `sed` ?

Comment: You don't need that space between `%` and `s`. You don't need that `%` (and the following space) between `:` and `g` because `:g[lobal]` works on the whole buffer by default. Your commands should be `:%s/one/two/g` and `:g/found/d`. The (weird, I don't know where you got it from) way you use to write your commands is probably what prevents you from doing `:h :s` and `:h :g` and find your answer by yourself.

Comment: @Kent: Does `:s` not use `sed` to perform the substitutions?

Comment: @Moeb perl can `s/../../` to do substitution, sed can do substitution by `s/../../`, vim too. but they have nothing to do with each other. the common part is just, they all use regex. If you go more deep, sed's regex, perl's regex and vim's regex are different too. so shortly, vim `:s` has nothing to do with `sed`. you can execute it under windows OS, without sed installed.

Answer (score 8):

I guess you are confused with `:g[lobal]`, `:s[ubstitute]` and `:[range]delete`

let's make some example:

`g` is a **flag** of `:s`:

- `:s/foo/bar/`  : replace only the **first** `foo` with `bar` in **current** line
- `:s/foo/bar/g`  : replace **all** `foo` with `bar` in **current** line
- `%:s/foo/bar/`  : for each line in the **whole** file, replace only the **first** `foo` with `bar`
- `%:s/foo/bar/g`  : replace **all** `foo` with `bar` in **whole file** (all lines)

`:g` as **`:global` command**: `:g` can do with any commands, not only `d`

- `:g/foo/d` : delete **all** matched lines default range is `%`
- `:%g/foo/d` : same as above
- `:1,30g/foo/d`: from line 1-30, remove all lines contain `foo`
- `:g/foo/normal >>`: indent all lines, which match `foo` (not only work with `d`)
- `:g/foo/y A`: yank all matched (`/foo/`) lines to register `a` (not only work with `d`)

`:d` command: (`:[range]d[elete]`)

- `:/foo/d` : `/foo/` here is a range. delete next matched line
- `:%d` : delete all lines (empty the file)
- `:%/foo/d` : this won't work. because you have two ranges (% and /foo/)
- `:/foo/dg` : this won't work either. no `dg` command
- `:g/foo/d` : this works, same as above(the `:g` section), but it is from `:global` command

I hope you get a bit clear. (or more confused? I hope not.. ^_^)

you may want to take a look followings

```
:h :s
:h :g
:h :d
:h range
```

Answer (score 4):

To explain little differently:

### `:% g/found/d`

Here, `g` is a shortened form of [:g[lobal]](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g), which has the following format:

```
:[range]g/pattern/[command]
```

And it works by:

1. scanning each lines within `[range]` (if no `[range]` is specified, *all lines* are scanned),
2. marking all matching `pattern`, and
3. executing the given `[command]`.

NOTE: All occurrences of the matching `pattern` within `[range]` are marked *before* executing the `[command]`. The commands are only executed to which the marked matching `pattern`.

### `:% s/one/two/g`

Here, `g`is one of the `[flags]` from [:s[ubstitution]](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_10.html#10.2) command, which has the following format:

```
:[range]s[ubstitute]/pattern/string/[flags]
```

And it works by:

1. scanning each lines within `[range]` (if no `[range]` is specified, only *current line* is scanned),
2. marking all matching `pattern`,
3. substituting the `pattern` found from above two conditions with `string`, and
4. calling `[flags]` (e.g. "c" for confirmation, "g" for all occurrences).

NOTE: `g` here is a *localized* flag for `:s[ubstitution]` and not *universally* used with other commands, unlike `:g[lobal]` command.

### Using `:g[lobal]` and `:s[ubstitute]` together

Replacing `[command]` from `:g[lobal]` command with `:s[ubstitution]`, we get the following format:

```
:[range_g]g/pattern_g/[range_s]s/pattern_s/string_s/[flags]
```

By analyzing, we learn the following:

1. Our world is limited to the matching `pattern_g` within `[range_g]`.
2. Within this limited world, we are executing the command `:s[ubstitute]`.
3. This `:s[ubstitute]` is executed only if matching `pattern_s` occurs within `[range_s]`.

### Example:

Given the following text:

```
stackoverflow.com/
stackexchange.com/
stackoverflow.com 
stackexchange.com
www.stackoverflow.com
www.stackexchange.com
http://www.stackoverflow.com
http://www.stackexchange.com // your cursor is placed here
```

CASE 1: `:g/com/d`

```
// all lines are deleted
```

CASE 2: `:g/com$/d`

```
stackoverflow.com/
stackoverflow.com/
// all lines containting com at the end are deleted
```

CASE 3: `:g/com$/s/exchange/overflow/g`

```
stackoverflow.com/
stackexchange.com/
stackoverflow.com 
stackoverflow.com // changed
www.stackoverflow.com
www.stackoverflow.com // changed
http://www.stackoverflow.com
http://www.stackoverflow.com // changed
```

CASE 4: `:1,7g/com$/s/exchange/overflow/g`

```
stackoverflow.com/
stackexchange.com/
stackoverflow.com 
stackoverflow.com // changed
www.stackoverflow.com
www.stackoverflow.com // changed
http://www.stackoverflow.com
http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

CASE 5: `:1,7g/com$/4,6s/exchange/overflow/`

```
stackoverflow.com/
stackexchange.com/
stackoverflow.com 
stackoverflow.com // changed
www.stackoverflow.com
www.stackexchange.com
http://www.stackoverflow.com
http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

CASE 6: `:1,7g/com$/4,6s/exchange/overflow/g`

```
stackoverflow.com/
stackexchange.com/
stackoverflow.com 
stackoverflow.com // changed
www.stackoverflow.com
www.stackexchange.com // changed 
http://www.stackoverflow.com
http://www.stackexchange.com
```

CASE 7: `:s/exchange/overflow/g`

```
stackoverflow.com/
stackexchange.com/
stackoverflow.com 
stackexchange.com
www.stackoverflow.com
www.stackexchange.com
http://www.stackoverflow.com
http://www.stackoverflow.com // changed. only current line is executed
```

Answer (score 1):

`s//g` is a global replace on the line.  `g/` is a global replace on the document.  In the first case, `%s` does a replace on the entire document.  Without the `g` at the end, it would still do a replace on the entire document, but only on the first instance of each line.  `%/` is invalid syntax, but `://d` will replace the next line found similar to how `:s//` will replace on the current line.  Note that you don't need `%g`.  Just `g` in your example will do the same thing.